# how to make hive take only specific files as input from hdfs folder

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have the following folder structure in hdfs

```
  /input/data/yyyy/mm/dd/
```

and inside it data files, for example:

```
/input/data/2013/05/01/
      file_2013_05_01_01.json // file format yyyy_mm_dd_hh
      file_2013_05_01_02.json // file format yyyy_mm_dd_hh
      ....
```

I've defined hive external table for this folder:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE input_data (
    vr INT, ....
)
PARTITIONED BY (tsp STRING)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

adding for each folder a partition as following:

```
   alter table input_data ADD PARTITION (tsp="2013-05-01") LOCATION '/input/data/2013/05/01/';
```

The following query will take as input all files in date 2013-05-01

```
select ... from input_data where tps="2013-05-01"
```

How can I take only files of specific hour? without changing the hdfs structure to put each hour in separate folder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could make use of a virtual column called `INPUT__FILE__NAME`. It is one of the 2 two virtual columns provided by Hive 0.8.0 and onward and represents the input file's name for a mapper task. So you could do something like this :

```
select ... from input_data 
where tps="2013-05-01" 
and INPUT__FILE__NAME='file_2013_05_01_01.json';
```

HTH

Answer (score 3):

You could make use of the following construct:

```
SELECT 
   *
FROM
   my_input_data
WHERE
   INPUT__FILE__NAME LIKE '%hh.json';
```

Here `hh` is your desired hour and `INPUT__FILE__NAME` is the virtual column available to hive queries while processing a given file.