# Hive Query having virtual column INPUT__FILE__NAME in where clause gives exception

Tags: hadoop, hive, external

Executing hive query with filter on virtual column INPUT__FILE__NAME result in following exception.

```
hive> select count(*) from netflow where INPUT__FILE__NAME='vzb.1351794600.0';
FAILED: SemanticException java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find field input__file__name from [org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.UnionStructObjectInspector$MyField@1d264bf5, org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.UnionStructObjectInspector$MyField@3d44d0c6, 
.
.
.
org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.UnionStructObjectInspector$MyField@7e6bc5aa]
```

This error is different from the one we get when column name is wrong

```
hive> select count(*) from netflow where INPUT__FILE__NAM='vzb.1351794600.0';
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 1:35 Invalid table alias or column reference 'INPUT__FILE__NAM': (possible column names are: first, last, ....)
```

But using this virtual column in select clause works fine.

```
hive> select INPUT__FILE__NAME from netflow group by INPUT__FILE__NAME;
Total MapReduce jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks not specified. Estimated from input data size: 4
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapred.reduce.tasks=<number>
Starting Job = job_201306041359_0006, Tracking URL = http://192.168.0.224:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201306041359_0006
Kill Command = /opt/hadoop/bin/../bin/hadoop job  -kill job_201306041359_0006
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 12; number of reducers: 4
2013-06-14 18:20:10,265 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2013-06-14 18:20:33,363 Stage-1 map = 8%,  reduce = 0%
.
.
.
2013-06-14 18:21:15,554 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%
Ended Job = job_201306041359_0006
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Job 0: Map: 12  Reduce: 4   HDFS Read: 3107826046 HDFS Write: 55 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
OK
hdfs://192.168.0.224:9000/data/jk/vzb/vzb.1351794600.0
Time taken: 78.467 seconds
```

I am trying to create external hive table on already present HDFS data. And I have extra files in the folder that I want to ignore. Similar to what is asked and suggested in following stackflow questions
[how to make hive take only specific files as input from hdfs folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16844758/how-to-make-hive-take-only-specific-files-as-input-from-hdfs-folder)
[when creating an external table in hive can I point the location to specific files in a direcotry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269203/when-creating-an-external-table-in-hive-can-i-point-the-location-to-specific-fil)

Any help would be appreciated.
Full stack trace I am getting is as follows

```
2013-06-14 15:01:32,608 ERROR ql.Driver (SessionState.java:printError(401)) - FAILED: SemanticException java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find field input__
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find field input__file__name from [org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.object
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.pcr.PcrOpProcFactory$FilterPCR.process(PcrOpProcFactory.java:122)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lib.DefaultRuleDispatcher.dispatch(DefaultRuleDispatcher.java:89)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lib.DefaultGraphWalker.dispatch(DefaultGraphWalker.java:87)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lib.DefaultGraphWalker.walk(DefaultGraphWalker.java:124)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lib.DefaultGraphWalker.startWalking(DefaultGraphWalker.java:101)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.pcr.PartitionConditionRemover.transform(PartitionConditionRemover.java:86)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.Optimizer.optimize(Optimizer.java:102)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.analyzeInternal(SemanticAnalyzer.java:8163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer.analyze(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:258)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ExplainSemanticAnalyzer.analyzeInternal(ExplainSemanticAnalyzer.java:50)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer.analyze(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:258)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:431)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:335)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:893)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:259)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:216)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:412)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:755)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:613)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find field input__file__name from [org.apache.hadoop.hive.ser
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.ppr.PartitionPruner.prune(PartitionPruner.java:231)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.pcr.PcrOpProcFactory$FilterPCR.process(PcrOpProcFactory.java:112)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find field input__file__name from [org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.UnionStructObjectInspector$MyF
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.ObjectInspectorUtils.getStandardStructFieldRef(ObjectInspectorUtils.java:344)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.UnionStructObjectInspector.getStructFieldRef(UnionStructObjectInspector.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeColumnEvaluator.initialize(ExprNodeColumnEvaluator.java:57)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeGenericFuncEvaluator.initialize(ExprNodeGenericFuncEvaluator.java:128)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.ppr.PartExprEvalUtils.prepareExpr(PartExprEvalUtils.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.ppr.PartitionPruner.pruneBySequentialScan(PartitionPruner.java:328)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.ppr.PartitionPruner.prune(PartitionPruner.java:219)
        ... 24 more
```